# Serialize/ Deserialize (fairly) Simple Objects in CLR for RESTful Web Services

Tags: c#, rest, serialization, clr, sqlclr

I have some CLR-based procedures in my SQL Server database that need to consume a RESTful web service, POSTing lists and retrieving collections of statuses.

I thought I could use the `JavaScriptSerializer` and use JSON, but I'm having a lot of trouble getting the SQL Server to let me (`JSON.NET` and `System.Script.Serialization` not being a assemblies I'm allowed to play with, apparently, and the dependency trees gets kinda ugly).

So then I thought, I could use the XmlSerializer, but it seems to be expecting a lot of metadata (contract-style) stuff that the REST service doesn't provide, and it doesn't seem to let you cast your resultant XML to a particular type (like `Dictionary<int, string>`, or `decimal[]`) like I would expect with the `JavaScriptSerializer` or the `JSON.NET` serializer.

I've spent the last hour looking for what seems like it should be a simple answer, or a simple method, and I'm hoping my Google-fu just has ebola.  I can't find any official recommendation on how to do this, and it seems crazy to even contemplate rolling my own serializer/ deserializer when this has to come up all the time.

How do you parse RESTful service requests and responses from a CLR assembly without going through code heroics?

Comment: Well, I know you can't cast to a dictionary from XML because XML can't enforce unique keys.  The best you can do is IEnumerable<KeyValuePair>, I think.

Comment: I have the excact same problem like you , did you come up with solution for that ?

Answer (score 1):

Create POCOs that match the XML you are trying to parse (you can use annotations to make the object model match the XML model), then use XMLSerializer to parse to a object graph of those POCOs.

This site will help you make that work, since normally the system generates dynamic assemblies to accomplish this (and SQL won't like that):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3fa5dce3-b0f3-44f8-9b7b-65439f1c98ae/cannot-deploy-xmlserializers-clr-assemblies

Are you sure this has to be done/should be done at all in the database?

Comment: Well, no, it should be done in a managed code assembly, but I do need to consume the API resources from the database.  Can you elaborate on the POCOS to make the simple objects I referenced above?